What tool is used to create the Iosevka fonts?
If I understand correctly, the Iosevka fonts (available online at https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka) are not created using graphical user interface software such as FontForge, but are programmed.
I have come across many .ptl files in the repository, but I can't find any mentions to this language online.

the code is run by npm so javascript,the ptl is some kind of template for the system

@joojaa In Iosevka/packages/font-glyphs/src/letter, there are 0 lines of JS

@joojaa But my question is about this PTL language

Ok now that github works a bit better than yesterday, adter a bit of searching i found the answer. You can also find this answer on reddit if you dont want to read the code. But in reality someones pet language is not a Graphic design question. Please consider closing this post

@joojaa Come on I was told on stack overflow to post my question here

Yeah i noticed from search cache. When someone on a different forum says ask here, they dont generally know whats ontopic here unless that person has a significant rep here. They just dont want to deal with it. This is definitely not a graphic design topic. I mean i can make my own crayons but that does not mean making crayons is a graphic design question

@joojaa: We cannot decide whether a question is on-topic based on the answer. The question was which tool was used to create a graphic-design product. That is a graphic-design question; it’s about design processes and similar. The answer is that it’s a special programming language, but that doesn’t make it automatically a Stack Overflow question (and we also don’t have to meticulously avoid all overlap between the sites). Details about said programming language will probably not be suited for Graphic Design SE, but that’s not what is asked here.

@Wrzlprmft no the question was what programming language the PTL file is. Which is out of topic. Since there are allready people downvoting this its may be a good idea to mark it as offtopic. But its true that this may be accepted does not really matter since its been answered because i was interested in the question. Its also not a general tool, its a pet programming language by the author nobody else really uses it.

After a bit of digging i found that the language is PatEL, which is a language by same author you can find the docs here:
https://github.com/be5invis/PatEL
So own custom language by the author which is something inspired by lisp. Not used in much else.
